# Access nodejs with web javascript but hitting XSS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-site

I have a nodejs app that runs a web server and works as a web API. Simple `GET`s to interact with it. My goal is to be as accessible as possible by any language or programmatic scenario. My biggest problem is that javascript run in the browser can't hit it because the browser (specifically chrome) prevent cross site scripting. I'm open to any ideas that allow this. I want any site to be able to make requests against the url, sort of like how twitter has a javascript API.

I've tried using jQuery's ajax with JSONP but I was having all sorts of problems. Either it wouldn't go through or if it did go through I wouldn't get the response.

If there's a pure javascript way, I'd prefer that because of it having fewer dependencies.

Comment: Implement CORS in your Node.js server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-nodejs

Comment: Added two headers in my node app and it worked wonders.